# Given four real numbers $a,b,c,d$ so that $1\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq d\leq 3$. Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\leq ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials, convexity-inequality

> Given four real numbers $a, b, c, d$ so that $1\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq d\leq 3$. Prove that
> $$a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}+ d^{2}\leq ab+ ac+ ad+ bc+ bd+ cd$$

My solution
$$3a- d\geq 0$$
$$\begin{align}\Rightarrow d\left ( a+ b+ c \right )- d^{2}= d\left ( a+ b+ c- d \right ) & = d\left ( 3a- d \right )+ d\left ( \left ( b- a \right )+ \left ( c- a \right ) \right )\\ 
 & \geq b\left ( b- a \right )+ c\left ( c- a \right ) \\ 
 & \geq \left ( b- a \right )^{2}+ \left ( c- a \right )^{2} \\ 
 & \geq \frac{1}{2}\left ( \left ( b- a \right )^{2}+ \left ( c- a \right )^{2}+ \left ( c- a \right )^{2} \right )\\
 & \geq \frac{1}{2}\left ( \left ( b- a \right )^{2}+ \left ( c- b \right )^{2}+ \left ( c- a \right )^{2} \right )\\
 & = a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc- ca
\end{align}$$
How about you ?

Comment: Mr. @MichaelRozenberg I'm looking forward to your solution and your QUESTION.

Comment: How do you assume $3a-d \ge 0$? Something seems wrong with the question unless I have understood wrong. Are $a = b = c = 1, d = 4$ valid values or not?

Comment: For all real values of $a, b$ and $c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca$. Same should hold true for $a, b, c, d$. Are you sure  inequality says $\le$ and not $\ge$?

Comment: @MathLover both case show that inequality is completely wrong. Try $a=b=c=d=1$

Comment: @MathLover while what you said is correct, the inequality is symmetrical, so you can assume either way without loss of generality (e.g, $a\ge d$).

Comment: @QuangHoang of course you can choose any arbitrary values but if you assume $(3a-d) \ge 0$, next set of steps are not correct. Please go through his steps.

Comment: If $a = 1 + \epsilon$ and $d= 4-\delta$ than $3a - d =-1 + 3\epsilon + 4\delta \ge 0$ only if $3\epsilon + 4 \delta \ge 1$.  There is *utterly* no reason to assume that is true.  $a =1$ and $d =4$ is an obvious counter example.  But so is $a = 1.2$ and $d= 3.95$.

Comment: "he inequality is symmetrical, so you can assume either way without loss of generality "  No.  there is a *HUGE* loss of generality.  If you choose an $a$ and $d$ so that $3a-d \ge 0$ you get a *very* different result than if you choose an $a$ and $d$ where $3a-d < 0$.  Yes, your choice are "arbitrary" but they can not be *specific*. Choosing $a = 2.1; b=2.5; c=3.1; d= 3.7$ is *also* arbitrary. But they are not *general*.  Choosing them will not prove all cases.  There *IS* a loss of generality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $$(a,b,c,d)=(1,1,1,4).$$
For these values we need to prove that $$19\leq15,$$ which is not so true.

The following inequality is true already.

> let $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset[1,3].$ Prove that:
> $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\leq ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd.$$

We can prove this inequality by the Convexity.

Indeed, let $f(a)=ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd-a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2$.

Thus, $f$ is a concave function, which says that $f$ gets a minimal value for an extreme value of $a$,

id est, for $a\in\{1,3\}$.

Similarly, for $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Thus, it's enough to check our inequality for $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset\{1,3\}$, which gives that our inequality is true.

Comment: I fixed smth. Thanks.

Comment: Mr. @MichaelRozenberg what does #arqady mean ?

Comment: @NANG TOAN DO it comes from a name of my father.

Comment: What is his name ?

Comment: Arkadii, but arqady is stranger.

Comment: Israeli name is nice !

Comment: NANG TOAN DO is also a wordplay. In Vietnam, we don't call by family name. I'm Đặng Hải Đăng. So Đăng is all a bomber means Đăng Toàn Nổ -> Đổ Toàn Năng. But Đỗ is a well-known family name, so I call it DO TOAN NANG (Đổ is fail in Vietnamese).

Comment: Toàn Năng is all-stars, but a funny name (no name is that), so it's only my nickname on Vietnamese Math Forum.